# How to show multiple color in grids(vertically and horizontally) of graph at run time

Tags: android

I am trying to create a graph (using AchartEngine.jar) that shows heart Beat(received from bluetooth device) on Y-axis and Time on X-axis. But I need to show a graph zone Wise in vertical with different color.

Suggest me if you had any solution.